# Matlab standalone application with parallel toolbox (parfor loop in deployed applications)

Tags: parallel-processing, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler, parfor

I use Matlab R2016a and guide.
I created an application that uses parfor loop. It works great in Matlab environement, but when deployed (standalone application) the time the parfo loop takes is the same as the foor loop; I mean there is no parallel compuiting in the depolyed application.

The documentation for deployement with parallel computing, for the latest versions of Matlab is  there :
https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/use-the-parallel-computing-toolbox.html

I folowed all the procedure explained there (except for the clusterProfile it has .settings as extension in the oldest version instead of .mlsettings), but it did not work.

Please help, if you have any idea how to solve this.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer :

I just compiled using the absolute path of my prefdir commande :

mcc -a C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Roaming/MathWorks/MATLAB/R2016a/parallel.Settings -e myProgram.m;

use the commande prefdir, to guet the path.